# Probability of infinite intersection of events

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory, stochastic-processes

Given that $\{X_i=z\}\subset\{X_{i+1}=z\}$ i want to prove that

$P(X_i=z \space \text{for all}\space i \geq 1)=\lim_{n \to \infty }P(X_i=z \space\text{for}\space i=1,...,n)$.

Here is my idea to prove it. If i can show that

$\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty \{X_i=z\}=\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \bigcap_{i=1}^n\{X_i=z\}=\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n$

then i can use $\sigma$-continuity because $A_{n+1}\subset A_n$ so

$P(X_i=z \space \text{for all}\space i \geq 1)=P(\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty \{X_i=z\})=P(\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n)=P(\lim_{n \to \infty }A_n)=\lim_{n \to \infty }P(A_n)=\lim_{n \to \infty }P(X_i=z \space\text{for}\space i=1,...,n)$

But i have trouble proving

$\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty \{X_i=z\}=\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \bigcap_{i=1}^n\{X_i=z\}=\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n$

Comment: Given $\{X_i = z\} \subset \{X_{i+1} = z\}$, both events you're taking the probability of in the question are just $\{X_1 = z\}$, so the limit holds trivially as the limit of a constant sequence.  I somewhat expect you either have a typo or don't want to include that assumption.

Comment: Thanks for your Help. Just for clarification you could also say that $\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty \{X_i=z\} =\{X_1=z\}=\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \bigcap_{i=1}^n \{X_i=z\}$.